What is this weapon used in The Peacemaker?
In The Peacemaker (1997, starring George Clooney), at the 1 hr, 8 min mark, there is a scene where the truck with nukes stops at a checkpoint, and in the end, the bad guys kill the checkpoint soldiers.
The truck driver fires an interesting weapon that looks like a one-shot grenade launcher—like a 40mm tube, 60–70 cm long with a handle. Can anyone identify it?

Can you include a screenshot?

This is the scene OP is referring to; https://i.sstatic.net/Z4NfrTAm.png

@BoppityBop - You might want to note that we are currently discussing whether to allow "Identify-this" on the site; https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5033/49

This is a Schermuly Multi-Purpose Gun

Manufactured by the British company Webley & Scott, the Schermuly Multi-Purpose Gun is a single shot break action riot gun based on a World War II era signal pistol. The gun has a removable buttstock, can be fitted with several different barrel lengths and can have an adapter to fire shotgun cartridges fitted making it a versatile weapon.


The driver is using it (with the buttstock removed) as a small, portable grenade launcher.


Per Internet Movie Firearm Database - The Peacemaker

